# How to modify column row in pandas based on another column row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

### Pseudo code:

```
For each value in column A:
     if value == NaN then replace value with corresponding column B value
```

### **Given:**

[image: GIVEN]

### **Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: `df = df.bfill(axis=1)`?

Comment: kindly share data, not pics. you can try `df.bfill(1)` and see if that works